# What is Thanos's weapon called?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, props, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Thanos wields a kind of "double sword".  I have no idea what this weapon is.

[image: Thanos with his "double sword"]

<sup>(Image source: [Thanos' new Avengers: Endgame weapon has been revealed](https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a27003272/avengers-endgame-thanos-weapon-revealed-marvel/)）</sup>

I'm wondering what kind of weapon this is, and if it has a name less clunky than "double sword".  I saw someone online call it a "glaive", but that doesn't seem accurate.

**Question**: What is Thanos's weapon called?

Comment: *Titan Bat'Leth* ? ☺

Comment: A glaive is just another name for a sword

Comment: @GordonBennett I've never seen the word "Glaive' refer to a sword. The only two meanings I have come across are of the historical [polearm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaive) (specifically one with a single-edged blade), and the silly boomerang thing from [Krull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_(film)) whose general design and function has made its way into games like Warcraft.

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/glaive - A sword or broadsword you didn't try very hard @Ingolifs

Comment: Given that the dictionary definition missed its most common usage, I question how accurate it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is Thanos's weapon called?

## As of now, a name hasn't been given to Thanos' weapon

in the same sense that Thor's hammer has the name Mjolnir. So at least for now, we can only refer to Thanos' weapon using general terms, that being a **double-bladed sword**.

---

> I'm wondering what kind of weapon this is

### What we know so far

1. **Not only is the sword double-bladed, but it's also *double-edged*.** One blade has a cutting edge facing outwards from the wielder, the other blade with a cutting edge faces inward. This is to say that each individual blade is not double-edged.
2. **The material it's made of is stronger than Vibranium.** During his fight with Thor, Ironman and Captain America, Thanos manages to chip away at Cap's shield using his double-bladed sword until less than half of the shield remained.
3. **Joe Russo referred to it as "the greatest weapon".** [In an interview with Comic Book NOW's host Brandon Davis](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2019/05/07/avengers-endgame-thanos-double-bladed-weapon-sword-origin-metal/), Russo gets asked what the sword is made of (@23:56) --

> BD: First off, I have a really quick question. Did you make any decision of what his blade is made of? Because it was able to break Vibranium.
>
> JR: Thanos is a thousand year old character who has fought everyone in the universe. He the greatest, he's the Genghis Khan of the universe, he would have the greatest weapon. He knows of Eitri, he's been to Eitri to have his glove created. Did he have them create his blade as well? Potentially. But it's interesting that it could destroy the shield."

4. [Watching this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xJCf4uPgK4), it's *extremely* impractical IRL.

### What we don't know

- Who made it (though Russo hinted that maybe Eitri did).
- The name of the material it's made of.
- If the weapon even has a name.

---

> I saw someone online call it a "glaive"

When I first saw it, it kind of reminded me of a crude version [the Warglaives of Azzinoth](https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/110/images/thumbnails/8258-1-1352210714.png), from World of Warcraft. But I don't know enough about blades/weapons to make the distinction of if Thanos' weapon (or the Warglaives for that matter) can really be classified as a glaive.

Answer (score 1):

**It's just a [Double-edged sword](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Double-Edged_Sword)**

It doesn't have an official name or specific names like Mjolnir or Stormbreaker.

Comment: What a terrible name: “double-edged” is a term that absolutely does apply to real-world swords, but refers to a sword (or other blade) that has sharpened edges on both sides. Compare a double-edged [longsword](https://www.darksword-armory.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/black-knight-medieval-sword-1312-medieval-weapon-hilt.jpg) against, say, a single-edged [katana](https://shop.r10s.jp/v-road/cabinet/ikou_20100205_005/img10495907553.jpg). Meanwhile, Thanos’s weapon has two *blades*, and for that matter, they appear to each be *single-edged!*

Comment: Anyway, it might be worth noting that Thanos’s weapon is nonsense, from a realism perspective. The second blade just makes it harder to Thanos to swing it around, with basically zero benefit making up for that.

Comment: The most accurate term would be a *double-bladed sword* that's *double-edged*. A single-bladed sword can also be double-edged, so what you have in your response isn't quite the best term for it if nothing else is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into this today and I can't respond via a comment to what [Charles](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/31426/charles) said based on Stackexchange's minimum credit system, but a glaive is simply a European polearm. I guess all glaives are polearms, but not all polearms are glaives (unless you're speaking English and using the term broadly). It was probably called a glaive because it looks like a double edged Asian weapon, similar to the Chinese [guandao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guandao) or Korean [woldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woldo).

Personally, I favour calling it a double glaive/polearm over a sword, based on its strong resemblance to those weapons.